# Linux: Samba password required for guest account

Tags: linux, windows, samba

I have the following problem accessing a samba share from a windows pc. The samba share is meant to be accessible without the user having to enter a username or password. 
It works if the pc with the samba share is in a domain.

If the pc with the samba share is connected point to point to a windows pc, then a username/password is required on the windows pc. To make it more interesting, this is not always the case, for some pcs the password is required, for others not.

So my question is: Why do I sometimes need to enter a password when I want to access the samba share via a point to point connection?

Samba configuration:

```
[global]
        max log size = 128
        load printers = No
        show add printer wizard = No
        disable spoolss = Yes
        domain master = No
        security = share
        netbios name = %h
        server string = %h
        workgroup = lgwg
        guest account = nobody
        invalid users = root
        wins support = No
        passdb backend = smbpasswd
        keep alive = 10

[autologger]
        comment = blabla
        path = /share
        force user = nobody
        guest ok = Yes
        guest only = Yes
        public = Yes
        available = Yes
        browsable = Yes
        writable = Yes
        printable = No
        read only = No
        hide files = /.empty*/.dontremove*
        veto files = /.empty*/.dontremove*
        hide unreadable = Yes
        hide dot files = Yes
        hide special files = Yes
```

Answer (score 1):

set guest account = nobody to guest account = ftp
this known to work on some distro's